# How to find MLS data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I often see the same real estate listings across many different websites. Is there a central place where websites get their data from? How can I find an API or XML feed or aomething with real estate listings for a certain area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leonel, there are local Realtor Associations. They each operate their own database and MLS information. They then optionally share it with other groups like realtor.com, trulia.com, zilliw.com etc. But the data always goes to the local city/region Realtor association.

There is IDX - limited data and VOW full data that Realtors can get feeds / data dumps for their website. Most of the local associations run systems that use the RETS interface to export data in a standard way.

So you essentially need to contact the local association, and usually need to be a member of the association.

You think it would be easy data to get, but it's actually pretty well guarded. Trulia worked hard to build the relationships to get the data.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick answer. I have a few contacts in the local real estate association, I'll probably give them a call tomorrow :)

Comment: Yeah my company has done 4 local MLS integrations now.  But, took me awhile to wrap my head around the industry. It's surprising how disconnected they all are. You think by now it would be mature and this data would be easy to access. But, they still fear if this data is easily accessible it will but Realtors out of a job.  Some of the local associations we work with are very stingy, others like Chicago give you everything.